# swig typemap for array argument being passed by reference

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am trying to use a C++ function of the following signature via swig in python:

```
foo(const double (&q)[3])
```

Is there a function in the swig standard lib that can help me ?

Here is where I come from. For the former signature of the function `foo(double q[3])` I used the following swig interface:

```
%include "carrays.i"

%array_class(double, doubleArray);
```

Now I am looking for something similar supporting the more complicated `const double (&q)[3]` argument.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SWIG Python fixed size array passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498128/swig-python-fixed-size-array-passed-by-reference)

Comment: I was hoping for some form of support by the swig standard lib equivalent to carrays.i. Looking at [34.3.9 Pointers, references, values, and arrays](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn22) does not seem to mention references of arrays. So it seems using %inline is the only way to go.